# Custom Python interpreter version in zc.buildout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, buildout

I have a [zc.buildout](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/2.5.3) project which I'd like to use Python 3.5 for. I'd like to avoid using the system Python, as on RHEL7 the latest Python 3 package is Python 3.4.

Is there a way to tell Buildout in buildout.cfg that `bin/python` should be Python 3.5? I'm currently [doing something like this](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/tastyscrapy/blob/master/buildout.cfg) which does not seem to be working.

Comment: Just invoke bootstrap with the right Python. `python3.5 bootstrap.py` and `bin/buildout`.

Comment: So after further reading, @allcaps comment implies that Buildout no longer creates fully-isolated Python environments according to their documentation, which is unfortunate.